# Check for valid links if a dead URL redirects to a costum error page

Tags: java, testing, selenium, http-status-code-404, url-validation

I need to test(Selenium) if the links in a given page is valid or not. I found a good post about it here

http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/

But the problem is, what if a error page redirects to a **custom error page**? Then i would get a **200** or a **302** instead of a **404**. How should I go about checking the validity of URLs for webpages that redirect their 404s.

Comment: Then you should check for the custom error's elements. If they exist, then you're on custom error page

Comment: The title of the page or the element should be a good candidate to test this scenario

Comment: I'd disagree about using the browser.title element - it works and is simple, but if your content team or SEO decides that the page titles aren't friendly or on-brand and changes them without warning, it'll break your tests and it will always happen an hour before a sprint demo. This has happened to me. Use a page element instead.

Comment: That is all good, but what if the redirection is to the homepage or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should utilize an assertion of an element on the page with a known specific test.  Use a specific reusable function for this.

Then when you hit a page call the function as a check.  If you find the specific element present then click the browser back button after recording the URL.  If not you can continue your test as desired.  There is another post in regards to recursively finding all links and testing them.  [How to browse a whole website using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257802/how-to-browse-a-whole-website-using-selenium/24292170#24292170)

```
    if (checkError()) //calls specific check for the error on the custom error page
    {
      //Log URL
      string badURL = driver.Url();
      //Save somewhere in a list for output later...

      //navigate to previous page
      driver.navigate().Back();
    }
```

Comment: As I've said in the comment above, what if the broken link is redirected to the homepage or some other pages. I have seen some of the website do this.

Comment: In order to properly test there must be some "known" states.  You should have at least part of a URL that you know should be there that you can do a contains text test on.  If it truly is the same then check the page content for something that you know should be on that page.