# Cycle through every link on a page with Webdriver

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been asked to create a test which can cycle through all the links on a page with webdriver in C#.

I really don't where to begin with this, so sorry for not having any code to provide.

I'll need to somehow select all the links on the page and place them into an array or the like and them simply loop through them, click link, back to previous page, click next link etc.

Comment: You'll get a better response with a clearer question. Let's assume you are attempting what is commonly called a navigation test.

Comment: I cannot recommend enough the very nice "Coypu" which is a wrapper around selenium/webdriver. It's way easier to use than "bare" webdriver. https://github.com/featurist/coypu

Answer (score 3):

I assume it is something in the lines of:

```
        foreach (var item in _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")))
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(item.GetAttribute("href"));
        }
```

## Edit:

Note this is written from head and approximate solution using NUnit.

```
[TestFixture]
class UnitTests
{
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void FixtureSetup()
    {
        _driver = new ChromeDriver();
        _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(Defaultamount);
        _wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, Defaultamount);
    }
    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void FixtureTearDown()
    {
        _driver.Quit();
    }
    //...
}
```

Code would be something in the lines of :

```
    [TestCase("www.googel.com")]
    public bool TestAllWebpageLinks(string url, Result = true)
    {
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        var result = _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"))
            .Select(o=>o.GetAttribute("href"))
            .ToDictionary(o=>o,o=>TestPage(url,o));
        return result.All(o => o.Value);
    }
    public bool TestPage(string url, string link){
        try
        {
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
            _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='"+link+"']")).Click();     
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Just as a note, Resharper plugin will simplify running unit tests a lot.

Comment: This seems to be what I need, but I'm pretty new to all this, how would I make the test .Click each link in the foreach? So have it click link then .Navigate back to previous, click next link etc.

Comment: Your initial comment says its been edited but nothing has changed :S

Comment: +1 but seems a bit overkill (not really sure why you are `ToDictionary`'ing the whole list)

Comment: @Arran Well, he wanted to create a TEST. This is how to set up testing environment. The test itself goes to a page and gets all links. It will click all the links and some of them can fail. I made an assumption that if some do, then he wants to see what did and  dictionary will contain this info (link -> page load success). Assumed goal is to test if all pages successfully load. The dictionary is useful if something failed and he wants to see what failed - imagine break point at ´return result.All(o => o.Value);´.

Comment: So you are basically transforming the list into a list of something else. That's what `Select` was designed to do, not `ToDictionary`. Like I said, the solution works and works well, but you did not need to put it into a Dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Please look here: [How to browse a whole website using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257802/how-to-browse-a-whole-website-using-selenium/24292170#24292170)

Since you mentioned one page and not the whole site there are some straightforward ways.

populate an implementation of `IWebElements` with an xpath locator for `//a`...or get it by tagname as Margus mentions.

Then loop through this and click each `IWebElement` in the `IWebElements` list.  Save the `driver.Url` in a list of items for review or output later with whatever else you want to capture from the page.  You can validate here if you have known parameters to check for.  Then execute a `driver.Navigate().Back()`.  This will put you back in the previous spot to test the next element.  Might also want to save the href as well as Margus suggests and compare that with the `driver.Url` on the other page.

**Update based on comment**

```
public class Links
{
    public string LinkName { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string newPageUrl { get; set; }
}

string newPageUrl = "";
string linkName = "";
string href = "";
List<Links> links = new List<Links>();
foreach (IWebElement item in _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")))
{
    href = item.GetAttribute("href");
    linkName = item.text();
    item.click();
    newPageUrl = driver.Url();
    links.Add(new Links
         {
             NewPageUrl  = newPageUrl,
             Href = href,
             LinkName = linkName
         });
    driver.Navigate().Back();
}
```

Then your List will be a list of that class which will have the specific properties for each link you want as well as the navigation with the new url.  Then you can easily add something to this if you want to keep track of something else or test something else.

Comment: Going on the foreach Margus posted, how would I click each selected link? I've never used an IWebElements list before.

Comment: For each casts to a web element on each iteration, so the controls for the web element would be used.

Answer (score 0):

With Selenium-WebDriver you can simply call:

- driver.findElements(By.TagName("a")) to return a collection of matching webelements.

Or if you want more options you could use a library like http://sizzlejs.com/ with webdriver which would let you call something like:

- getElementsByTagName("a");

You could also use other external helpers like:

- FluentAutomation to help with your test code

It depends on your page and how the links are generated.

Answer (score 0):

This complete program might help you: The code is in Java

I am printing all the link Name.

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TrailRuns 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.googl.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        List<WebElement> objWEs = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

        for(WebElement ele:objWEs)
            System.out.println(ele.getText());
    }
}
```