# How can I programatically get URL of all pages in a website

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I want to get this using preferably java or if there is a way to do it using selenium webdriver, I dont want the links present in a page . I want a result like https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ gives a list of all page URLs in a domain. I dont need it like a tree or an xml, just plain simple URLs will do

Comment: What you're looking for is commonly referred to as a web crawler or web spider.  Try googling.

Comment: I googled it, most of what everyone is telling is to get the links of a page and traverse those and find more links in those pages using jsoup, or I can similarly do that using selenium webdriver, but I dont want that. That is a bit tedius and doesnt solve my purpose, my homepage lets say might point to a fifty links across many websites but my website only has 4 pages, and my homepage doesnot have link to all those four pages, then just to get for pages that's a lot of overhead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to browse a whole website using selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257802/how-to-browse-a-whole-website-using-selenium)

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for tags ( like href or a ) and then store the links in a list.

List links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("href"));