# Maven/Java Crawler - StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: java, maven, selenium, web-crawler

Im getting a StaleElementReferenceException but i dont know why? The crawler works properly and loops through the queued urls but fails with the StaleElementReferenceException error

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code and error.

Code

```
    package com.crawlerr.pageObjects;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Queue;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

    import com.crawler.common.ExcelUtils;
    import com.crawler.common.System_Constants;

    public class Crawler4 extends BaseClass
    {
        public static HashSet<String> alreadyListed = new HashSet<String>();
        public static Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();

        public Crawler4(WebDriver driver) {
            super(driver);
        }

        public static void Execute(int iTestCaseRow) throws Exception {
            crawl(ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestCaseRow,System_Constants.Col_BaseURL),iTestCaseRow);
        //  System.out.println("Stored"+Arrays.toString(alreadyListed.toArray()));
        }


        public static void crawl(String startingUrl, int iTestCaseRow)
        {
            queue.add(startingUrl);
            String newAddress;
            while ((newAddress = queue.poll())!=null)
            {
                processPage(newAddress, startingUrl, iTestCaseRow);
                //here you may add a code to do anything you wish with the page
            }
        }

        protected static void processPage(String url, String startingUrl, int iTestCaseRow)
        {
            try {
                System.out.println("Current URL-"+url );
                driver.get(url);
                    List<WebElement> crawlList = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
                    crawlList = findAllLinks();
                    String href;
                    System.out.println("Total number of elements found " + crawlList.size());
                      for (int i = 0; i < crawlList.size()-1; i++)
                      {
   /**this line throws the error**/ href =crawlList.get(i).getAttribute("href");
                        if (href!=null && isAddressValid(href,startingUrl))
                        {
                            if (!alreadyListed.contains(href))
                            {
                                System.out.println("Added to list - "+href);
                                alreadyListed.add(href);
                                queue.add(href);
                            }else{System.out.println("Already added to list - "+href);}
                        }else{System.out.println("Not valid - "+href);}
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }

            protected static boolean isAddressValid(String href, String startingUrl)
            {
                //href.contains(s)
               return href.contains(startingUrl);
            }

            private static List<WebElement> findAllLinks(){
                List<WebElement> elementList = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
                elementList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
                List<WebElement> finalList = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
                for (WebElement element : elementList){
                    finalList.add(element);
                }
                return finalList;
            }
    }
```

Output:

```
FAILED: main
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 20.06 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-PCD960U', ip: '192.168.1.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=42.0, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 164b1efc-9098-43b1-ad44-45da58b71f3c
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:326)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getAttribute(RemoteWebElement.java:149)
    at com.crawlerr.pageObjects.Crawler4.processPage(Crawler4.java:52)
    at com.crawlerr.pageObjects.Crawler4.crawl(Crawler4.java:36)
    at com.crawlerr.pageObjects.Crawler4.Execute(Crawler4.java:25)
    at com.crawler.Tests.Crawler_Test.main(Crawler_Test.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:821)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1131)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:773)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:623)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1018)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-PCD960U', ip: '192.168.1.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.cache.getElementAt(resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:9351)
    at <anonymous class>.Utils.getElementAt(file:///C:/Users/Craig/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous8982667753843323416webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:8978)
    at <anonymous class>.WebElement.getElementAttribute(file:///C:/Users/Craig/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous8982667753843323416webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12019)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/Craig/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous8982667753843323416webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12534)
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/Users/Craig/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous8982667753843323416webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:621)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: The code doesn't seem wrong to me... Try changing Firefox options when you instantiate the driver to use the cache...

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error when selenium is used for crawling webpages.
The StaleElementReferenceException indicates that the element you are trying to access has changed. This could be because (and not limited) of the following reasons :

1. Page Refresh
2. Element might have changed because of AJAX load
3. Element might have changed after the element was found because of a wait issue

In your code you are calling the `findAllLinks()` method to get the `crawlList`. After this you are iterating through the `crawlList`. Between the find operation and the iteration, any event might have occurred that made the element stale.

The only solution is to put a try catch around the code.

```
try {
    href = crawlList.get(i).getAttribute("href");

    if (href != null && isAddressValid(href, startingUrl)) {
        if (!alreadyListed.contains(href)) {
            System.out.println("Added to list - " + href);
            alreadyListed.add(href);
            queue.add(href);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Already added to list - " + href);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not valid - " + href);
    }

} catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
    // do nothing
}
```

You can also explore the possibility of putting an explicit wait to wait for all links to load in the `findAllLinks` method.

You can also check the following question for a recursive solution to a web crawler. [How to browse a whole website using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257802/how-to-browse-a-whole-website-using-selenium/24316831#24316831)